# Best SRID for worldwide data in Microsoft Sql Server geometry field?

Tags: sql-server, geometry, srid

I'm using Microsoft Sql Server 2012 to store geographical data related to hydrometeorological stations which are scattered around the globe (point layers and multipolygon layers).
My data is in WGS84 latitude-longitude coordinates, and I initially stored it in geography fields of SqlServer.

Later I had to move to geometry fields, because we started using GeoServer, and the plugin for GeoServer can't read geography fields, only geometry ones.

As a start I saved my WGS84 data in the geometry fields (keeping the SRID 4326), and more or less it works, but it doesn't seem to me the best choice.
WGS84 coordinates are ellipsoidal ones, but in the geometry field they are treated like planar. Moreover, they are in degrees, and functions like STArea() return results in square degrees (?) that are meaningless to me. 
I'd need a reference system whose measurement unit is in meters.

Given that the objects I have to manage are scattered around the globe, I can't use a local projection system, like UTM33N for example.

So which could be a better SRID to convert my data to fit in geometry fields?

Comment: ...I don't think there is one...

Comment: I don't know if you've found a solution but it seems there is no support from Geoserver to fix this bug. It's almost 7 years but it's still there... and use a geometry data type for storing geography data it's simply ridiculous.
I've faced the same issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330897/sql-server-spatial-data-geometry-type